# Wordpress WC_Product_Variable not found

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

So I created a jquery script to fetch a data upon selecting from the drop down box, and show the amount of stocks but the thing is, it says: Fatal error: Class 'WC_Product_Variable' not found.

But when testing things out to directly run the file, it works, but when being fetched by jquery and show it so the page wont refresh it's not showing anything but instead throwing an error.

**change.js**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $( ".selectProductClass" )
        .on('change', function () {
            var str = "";
            $( "select.selectProductClass option:selected" ).each(function() {
              str += $( this ).val() + " ";
            });
            $.post('../wp-content/plugins/pos-extension-supplier/admin/pos-extension-product-stock.php"); ?>', {str:str}, function(data) {
                $('div.stocksLeftInHere').text(data);
            });
        });
    });
```

**product-stock.php**

```
    $product_id=$_POST['str'];
    echo $product_id;

    $handle=new WC_Product_Variable($product_id);
    $variations1=$handle->get_children();

    foreach ($variations1 as $value) {
        $single_variation=new WC_Product_Variation($value);
        $branch_name = implode(" / ", $single_variation->get_variation_attributes());

            if($branch_name == "Warehouse") {
                echo "".$single_variation->stock."";
                echo "";
                echo "stock."'>";
            }
    }
```

The problem is, it doesn't found the WC_Product_variable, Fatal error: Class 'WC_Product_Variable' not found.

Comment: What is your woocommerce version?

Comment: @RuhulAmin its 2.6.7

Comment: @RuhulAmin also to add, i think it somehow runs alone, what i mean is even using wp basic functions are not working also. I do call the file for running a few query but how will it be able to execute if the the classes aren't recognizable by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the Woocommerce classes are not already load when your script want to use `WC_Product_Variable`.

You need to include the file manually before calling the class

```
if(!class_exists('WC_Product_Variable')){
    include(plugin_url.'/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-product-variable.php');// adjust the link
}
```

I hope it helps ;-)

Comment: Thank you for answering, but the problem is, the file doesn't recognize the wp codes, so in short, when i'm going to run any functions like plugin_url, it doesn't recognize the function. 

I must be missing something. Since this file is being called upon just to show the fetched data, not being directly accessed.

Comment: you need to include your file in the main plugin file to load it in the wp enviromnent.

Comment: could you tell me how will i be able to do that, so i could check if my code is correct? Thank you so mch

Comment: it depends on your code (plugin or functions.php), for a php file, just an include_once or require to the file path is good. Just to test your script search define('WP_USE_THEME', false); require ('wp-load.php'); and if it's fit to you, add it at the top of product_stock.php

Comment: i included them on the main file of the plugin, but still not working, the file `pos-extension-product-stock.php` is not recognizing the wordpress functions, it's a like a standalone file inside the plugin, when i'm calling it on change.js it's not pulling out results, since i cannot use wordpress functions or woocommerce functions.

Comment: thanks for helping out, i had figured things out from the gist you sampled, and i will just do the rest out of it.